# Call jQuery function for each checkbox on Check/Uncheck All

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, checkbox

I have a table with multiple checkbox. For each time I check or uncheck a checkbox, it calls a function that send the parameters as a Model to the controller to update the database. Now I want to check/uncheck All, doing the same thing. I can check/uncheck them all, but the function is not called.

The checkbox

```
<input id="Include" class="checkBoxClass" type="checkbox" @(item.Include != "1" ? null : "checked")>
```

The function that sends the model to the controller

```
$('input:checkbox').change(function () {
        var tr = $(this).parents('tr:first');
        var Id = document.getElementById('Id').value;
        (...)
        var UserModel =
        {
            "Id": Id,
            (...)

        };
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(UserModel),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function () {
            }
        });
    });
```

And my check/uncheck all code

```
$('#ckbCheckAll').click(function (event) { 
            $('.checkBoxClass').each(function () {
                if (!this.checked)
                {
                $('.checkBoxClass').each(function () { 
                    $('.checkBoxClass').click("checked", true);
                });
                } else {
                $('.checkBoxClass').each(function () { 
                    $('.checkBoxClass').click("checked", false);
                });
            }
            });
        });
```

When I click the #ckbCheckAll button, all checkbox are checked/uncheked, but even that I have the .change on my "send model to controller" function, it dont work.

- What I'm doing wrong here?
- It's reliable doing this way?

Comment: why nest .checkBoxClass.each()?

Comment: @wlin To go throught each checkbox? It's useless?

Comment: yeah, let me fix a fiddle for you.

Comment: so, it should uncheck all boxes, if one of them is already check? and it should check all boxes when ALL of them is not check right?

Comment: if that's not the desire out come you need to have two button that check and uncheck all.

Comment: @wlin it should check all boxes no matter how many are checked (even if only last one to check). It could be with two buttons, no problem with that

Comment: ok so uncheck all if all are check?

Comment: @wlin same of check all. It should uncheck all, no matter how many are checked

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1zqbspzu/2/ like this?

Comment: @wlin Yes! will try with that!

Comment: @wlin, you're awesome. Please write an answer, to accept as correct (it can be the fiddle example)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82322/discussion-between-wlin-and-danielpm).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plain english, for check-all button if checkall box is click, check(if) with each(.each()) checkbox, if that box is check, fake a click(.click()) to uncheck it,

```js
$('input[type=checkbox]').change(function(){/*alert('change')*/});
$('.checkall').click(
    function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index,el){
        if(!this.checked) {
            $(el).click(); // check all box;
        } 
    });
  }    
);
$('.uncheckall').click(
    function() {
    $('input[type=checkbox]').each(function(index,el){
        if(this.checked) {
            $(el).click(); // uncheck all box;
        } 
    });
  }    
);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="checkbox"/>
<input type="button" value="check all" class='checkall'/>
<input type="button" value="uncheck all" class='uncheckall'/>
```

Comment: wlin, one more question. How can I prevent that the user have acess to the page before all checkbox are called? Can I make a pop up with a sppining wheel or something? How can I do that?